# How does to get five strings before the specified string?

Tags: python

My task is next. I have a file. I need to get the exact string from the file plus five strings that go before the specified string. I was trying it to do in this way:

```
import re
import glob
index = 0
ArrayListStringIndex = []
for filename in glob.glob('syslog'):
    file = open ((filename), "r")
    for SearchPrase in file:
        if re.search ((": New USB device found"), SearchPrase):
            ArrayListStringIndex.append(index)
        index = index + 1
```

But I don`t know how to connect the list of numbers of strings (ArrayListStringIndex = []) that I got with real string from file and respectively get five stings before.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: add the sample input and output

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. It would help if you provided a [mre], i.e. remove the irrelevant parts like `re` and `glob`, and add input, desired output, and actual output.

Comment: For example:
I have strings in a file:
yyyyyyyyyyy
ttttttttttttttttttttt
aaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
my_string
ffffffffffffffffffffff
gggggggggg
hhhhhhhhhh

Out should be:
aaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
my_string

Strings go in column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
import re
import glob

arrayListStringIndex = []
for filename in glob.glob('syslog'):
    file = open((filename), "r")
    file_lines = file.readlines()
    for index, searchPrase in enumerate(file_lines):
        if re.search ((": New USB device found"), searchPrase):
            arrayListStringIndex.append(index)
    for i in arrayListStringIndex:
        print(file_lines[i-5 if i > 5 else 0:i if i > 0 else 1])
```

That will print you all exact match lines with the 5 lines before them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) of length 5 to act as a cache. You just append each string as you're iterating, and the deque takes care of limiting the size for you, popping items off the front as needed. For example:

```
from collections import deque

strings = (f'a{n}' for n in range(20))  # Generator to act as a dummy file
d = deque([], 5)
target = '8'

for s in strings:
    if target in s:
        print(s, list(d))
    d.append(s)
```

Output:

```
a8 ['a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7']
a18 ['a13', 'a14', 'a15', 'a16', 'a17']
```

This also handles early occurrences effortlessly, e.g. with `target = '3'`:

```
a3 ['a0', 'a1', 'a2']
a13 ['a8', 'a9', 'a10', 'a11', 'a12']
```

Comment: Maybe add some comments on how the deque acts as a rolling window/list & what a rolling window is eventually. This answer is absolutely the right one, but I think it's a bit difficult to follow. And thanks for learning me about deque, didn't know about that specific collection.

Comment: @Thomas Done, thanks for the pointer. Though I don't know about using the term "window" cause to me that implies an underlying sequence, while "cache" doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, I was more thinking about a filter, often, this is a window that rolls over a sequence of data, here the file. But anyway, I upvoted the answer as it is maybe the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> message = "Always split your problem up in different parts, I'll try to purely answer on the title."
>>> words = message.split(" ")  # split the message in words
>>> index = words.index("different")  # find the index of your specific word
>>> for i in range(index - 5, index):  # iterate over the previous 5 words
...     if i > 0:
...             print(words[i])
... 
split
your
problem
up
in
```

Comment: This requires the words to be in a list, but OP's iterating over a file

Comment: I know, but this gives, I think, a starting point of how to do it. Chance are that the problem isn't that complex that the file not just can be copied into a list. A more nice solution would be to use a rolling array of 5 items and move & modulo the index the whole time.

Comment: Yeah, that's what my answer does. The `deque` is a rolling array.